# How to have two sql queries in a prepared statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, prepared-statement

I would like to do something like this.

```
PREPARE addFriend(INTEGER, INTEGER) AS
    INSERT INTO friendRelation (u_id, friendid) VALUES ($1, $2),
    INSERT INTO friendRelation (u_id, friendid) VALUES ($2, $1);
```

I do not see this in the docs, so either it can't be done or I am doing it wrong. If you can't have 2 queries in a prepared statment, is there some other feature of postgres that I don't know about that can do this?

Comment: you are supposed to be able to bind arrays into bind variables. i think it would be the best solution for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One prepared statement can't contain multiple statements… But this specific query can be re-written:

```
PREPARE addFriend(INTEGER, INTEGER) AS
    INSERT INTO friendRelation (u_id, friendid) VALUES ($1, $2), ($2, $1);
```

Alternatively, you could write a function to do the same:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addFriend(INTEGER, INTEGER) RETURNS VOID AS
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO …;
    INSERT INTO …;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note that you'll also have to run `CREATE LANGUAGE plpgsql;` at some point to add the plpgsql language to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is partially true, in your particular case you can run one insert for multiples rows.
But in case if you need to run more than one different queries you can use [WITH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) syntax

```
WITH data_t (u1_id, u2_id) AS (
  VALUES($1::INTEGER, $2::INTEGER)
), inserted1 AS (
  INSERT INTO friendRelation (u_id, friendid) SELECT u1_id, u2_id FROM data_t
)
INSERT INTO friendRelation (u_id, friendid) SELECT u2_id, u1_id FROM data_t;
```